# Interfaces with generic override

Tags: c#, interface

I have something like this:

```
public class ImplicitClientA : IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>, IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>

public class ImplicitClientB : ImplicitClientA, IGenericItems<IGenericItemC>
```

and I want to override `IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>` and `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>` in class `ImplicitClientB`.

Which is the best way?

- To create a virtual protected method in `ImplicitClientA` and
  override it in `ImplicitClientB`. or...
- To explicit implement `IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>` and
  `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>` in class `ImplicitClientB`.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpConsoleApplication.Tests
{
    public class InterfacesTest
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            var implA = new ImplicitClientA();
            IGenericItems<IGenericItemA> implA1 = implA;
            IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> implA2 = implA;

            Console.WriteLine("Text value for a is: " + implA1.Items.ToList()[0].GetTextValue());
            Console.WriteLine("Number value for a is: " + implA2.Items.ToList()[0].GetNumberValue());
            Console.WriteLine();

            var implB = new ImplicitClientB();
            IGenericItems<IGenericItemA> implB1 = implB;
            IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> implB2 = implB;
            IGenericItems<IGenericItemC> implB3 = implB;

            Console.WriteLine("Text value for b is: " + implB1.Items.ToList()[0].GetTextValue());
            Console.WriteLine("Number value for b is: " + implB2.Items.ToList()[0].GetNumberValue());
            Console.WriteLine("Date value for b is: " + implB3.Items.ToList()[0].GetDateValue());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }



    // Interfaces

    public interface IGenericItem
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IGenericItemA : IGenericItem
    {
        string GetTextValue();
    }

    public interface IGenericItemB : IGenericItem
    {
        int GetNumberValue();
    }

    public interface IGenericItemC : IGenericItem
    {
        DateTime GetDateValue();
    }


    public interface IGenericItems<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
    }


    // Classes

    public class ConcreteA : IGenericItemA
    {
        public ConcreteA(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        #region IGenericItemA Members

        public string GetTextValue()
        {
            return Id.ToString();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItem Members

        public int Id { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ConcreteB : IGenericItemB
    {
        public ConcreteB(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        #region IGenericItemB Members

        public int GetNumberValue()
        {
            return Id + 1;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItem Members

        public int Id { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ConcreteC : IGenericItemC
    {
        public ConcreteC(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        #region IGenericItemC Members

        public DateTime GetDateValue()
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItem Members

        public int Id { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }


    // Implicit interfaces implementation

    public class ImplicitClientA : IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>, IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>
    {

        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemA> Members

        public IEnumerable<IGenericItemA> Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemA>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteA(1));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> Members

        IEnumerable<IGenericItemB> IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>.Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemB>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteB(1));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ImplicitClientB : ImplicitClientA, IGenericItems<IGenericItemC>
    {
        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemC> Members

        public new IEnumerable<IGenericItemC> Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemC>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteC(2));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }


    // Explicit interfaces implementation
    public class ExplicitClientA : IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>, IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>
    {
        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemA> Members

        IEnumerable<IGenericItemA> IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>.Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemA>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteA(1));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> Members

        IEnumerable<IGenericItemB> IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>.Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemB>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteB(1));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ExplicitClientB : ImplicitClientA, IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>, IGenericItems<IGenericItemC>
    {
        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> Members

        IEnumerable<IGenericItemB> IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>.Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemB>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteB(2));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IGenericItems<IGenericItemC> Members

        IEnumerable<IGenericItemC> IGenericItems<IGenericItemC>.Items
        {
            get
            {
                var collection = new List<IGenericItemC>();
                collection.Add(new ConcreteC(2));
                return collection;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
The answer is no.

For example `ImplicitClientA` implements `IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>` and  `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>`.

Only one of them can be implicitly declared. The other must be explicitly declared. I guess the first is something like decorator to the class.

For the first I can declare the method as virtual and override it in child class `ImplicitClientB` or I can use a virtual protected method and override this in the child class `ImplicitClientB`.

So for `ImplicitClientA` I can refer to `Items` both like:

```
var implA = new ImplicitClientA();
var x = implA.Items;
```

or

```
IGenericItems<IGenericItemA> implA = new ImplicitClientA();
var x = implA.Items;
```

but if I want to use the `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>` the only way is

```
IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> implA = new ImplicitClientA();
var x = implA.Items;
```

Now for the child class `ImplicitClientB`.

If I want to do something else for `IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>` `Items` property, all I have to do, is to declare it virtual in `ImplicitClientA` and override it. Or use the virtual protected method as I mentioned earlier.

But in order to change the implementation for `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>` which is inherited by `ImplicitClientA`, I have to explicitly implement `IGenericItems<IGenericItemB>` in `ImplicitClientB`.

So I can refer to it only with one way:

```
IGenericItems<IGenericItemB> implB = new ImplicitClientB();
var x = implB.Items;
```

So everything works and everyone is happy!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't explicitly implement the interfaces.

They have already been implemented by `ImplicitClientA`, so if you do you'd have to be very careful to how you call your method (A implements an interface implicitly, B implements it explicitly):

```
B b = new B();
b.Method();               // calls the method defined in A
((A)b).Method();          // calls the method defined in A
((IInterface)b).Method(); // calls the method defined in B
```

I'd say the *responsibility* of implementing the `IGenericItems<IGenericItemA>` interface is with `ImplicitClientA`, so that's the right place to indicate that the functionality can be overridden.